# NHibernate linq - pass lambda function as a parameter to another lambda function

Tags: vb.net, linq, nhibernate, lambda, querying

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Person
   Public CountryId as Integer
   Public CityId as Integer
End Class

Public MustInherit Class BaseQuery
    Protected _IdsForFilter As Integer() = {1,2,3}

    Protected Function GetQuery(filter As Func(Of Person, Integer)) As Expression(Of Func(Of Person, Boolean))
        Return Function(p) _IdsForFilter.Contains(filter(p))
    End Function
End Class

Public Class CountryQuery
    Inherits BaseQuery

    Public Function GetQueryResult() As IEnumerable(Of Person)
        Using session = NhHelper.OpenSession()
            Return session.Query(Of Person)().Where(GetQuery(Function(p) p.CountryId))
    End Using            
    End Function
End Class
```

As you can see, I want to pass the field Selector for Person (Function(p) p.CountryId) as a lambda function in order to make my search generic (in BaseQuery).
The problem is that all compiles, but NHibernate does not return any result for this query. It seems that the lambda function sent in the parameter is not interpreted as lambda function but as an identifier of a delegate.

Please, any idea about this issue?
In other words, should I build an expression tree (but I don't know how to do it)?
Thaks a lot in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue by the help of LinqKit library, my function GetQuery becomes:

```
Protected Function GetQuery(filter As Func(Of Person, Integer)) As Expression(Of Func(Of Person, Boolean))
    Dim expr As As Expression(Of Func(Of Person, Boolean) = Function(p) _IdsForFilter.Contains(filter.Invoke(p))
    Return expr.Expand()
End Function
```

Thanks to LinqKit, my outer expression is combined with inner expression (the parameter p in given by outer expression and passed to inner lambda function)